# How can I change the background color of an image using GDI+?

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, gdi+

I want to know how to change the background color when I generate the image dynamically.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Just use the Graphics object `.Clear()` method, passing the color you wish to use for the background.

For example:

```
g.Clear(Color.Blue);
```

Answer (score 4):

It's simple:

```
Graphics graph = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
graph.Clear(Color.Yellow); // set color for background
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about a specific file format's "background color" field, I'm not sure if GDI+ supports that, but usually to set the background color of an image you'd fill a rectangle the size of the image with one color.

Example, assuming `g` is your [`Graphics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx) object, `image` is your [`Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) object, and `color` is your [`Color`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aspx) object:

```
g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(color), new Rectangle(Point.Empty, image.Size));
```

Also, as [FlipScript suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551316/how-to-change-the-background-color-using-gdi/4551342#4551342), you can use the [`Clear` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.clear.aspx). (I had no idea it existed!)

```
g.Clear(color);
```