# Black spots after rotating bitmap c#

Tags: c#, .net-core, bitmap, rotation

I need to rotate an image by a certain angle before further operations. After rotating, im left with black areas on my bitmap.

[Image after rotating by 30 degrees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4RFy.png)

I've managed to find similar issue in java right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48059788/how-to-remove-black-background-that-comes-after-rotating-bitmap).
Is there something like that for c#?

Im using the following code, that i found earlier on stack:

```
Bitmap Rotate_Image(Bitmap bmp, float angle)
    {
        Bitmap rotatedImage = new Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
        rotatedImage.SetResolution(bmp.HorizontalResolution, bmp.VerticalResolution);

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(rotatedImage))
        {
            // Set the rotation point to the center in the matrix
            g.TranslateTransform(bmp.Width / 2, bmp.Height / 2);
            // Rotate
            g.RotateTransform(angle);
            // Restore rotation point in the matrix
            g.TranslateTransform(-bmp.Width / 2, -bmp.Height / 2);
            // Draw the image on the bitmap
            g.DrawImage(bmp, new Point(0, 0));
        }

        return rotatedImage;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean with "Spots?"

Comment: Ya can we get some screenshots? The one you posted looks a like a rotated E that's slightly blurred.

Comment: why do you expect the corners to be anything but black?

Comment: By spots i mean black areas left after rotating.
The screenshot is at the first link.
About the color, the question is, is it possible to change the default black to other color - for example white?

Comment: Can you `g.Clear(Color.White)` with your desired background color before writing the rotated image? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551316/how-can-i-change-the-background-color-of-an-image-using-gdi

Answer (score 0):

Since your output is `*.png` I assume you want to use a transparent background. Just call `g.Clear(Color.FromArgb(0, default));` before applying `TranslateTransform`. Or just set any other background color if you like.

You also can set `g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;` to smoothen the sides of the rotated image.